# azure static web apps, managed api (functions): create a signal or alert from function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

Is it possible to create an azure monitoring alert or at least a signal which I can use under  "Application Insights => Monitoring => Alerts => Create Alert Rule => Select a Signal"?
Is there a way to define a custom signal type?
Maybe create a custom event via the app insights SDK and an alert based on that?
We use javascript/nodejs for our static web app API.

For example:

- Create a signal when a certain customer adds a ticket via the website
- the API gets called and customer of ticket = "john doe"
- the API creates a signal
- An alert rule fires based on that signal

Answer (score 0):

While you could perhaps use logs and alerts in combination to create an alert, a better approach would be to use [Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview) here.

In your code, you would post an event to a [custom topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-topics) and have a separate service subscribe to this topic and process the event accordingly. This will be near instantaneous compared the log approach because logs are processed before they are available to query, creating a delay in the original approach.

There are many [event handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-handlers) that you can choose from to handle your events.